# Swift ios difference between dismissViewControllerAnimated and exit

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

As a newbie on ios dev I wonder what the difference between `dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)` and dragging a line to the **"exit"** in storyboard are?

I have a view with a segue that leads into another view by modal presentation. Right now I am using `dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)` in order to go back to the prev VC. But I've seen som tutorials where they just drag a line to the exit icon/button in storyboard

Comment: Do you mean drag a line from the exit button to the view before it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dragging a line, you are presenting the previous view a second time instead of just dismissing the new view to get back to the original.  This method is not advised because it wastes memory every single time the exit button is clicked.  The previous view will keep on getting adding to the view stack which will accumulate memory.

Comment: Thanks for making some of it clear. So I should more or less stick with dismissViewControllerAnimated()?
Followup, lets say we have a table VC with a "push" segue to a second VC. That second VC will then automatically get a "<" back button in the navigation bar that works automatically. What type of dismiss segue does that back button in the navigation bar use?

Comment: 1. Yes, I would stick with dismissViewControllerAnimated. 2. Navigation controllers use dismissViewControllerAnimated and pop the top of the navigation stack instead of presenting the previous view again.

Answer (score 2):

Dismiss will not let you to prepare the unwinding process, it will simply go back to the previous view, while created segue from exit button gives you are chance to prepare the unwinding process where you can pass some model information from the view being dismissed to the previous view.